# Disable zoom and minimize in modal ViewController

Tags: cocoa, modalviewcontroller

I'm building a Cocoa app using XCode Storyboard and created a modal viewcontroller connected to an IBAction button click.
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51vfr.png)

Clicking the button successfully creates a new window.

However, I want to disable:
- Close
- Zoom
- Minimize

The funky thing is because it's a modal viewcontroller, I can't disable them like I can in a Windowcontroller.

I do have a ViewController.m file, where I'm able to set the Window title and restrict resizing using self.preferredContentSize. But not sure how to disable the close, zoom, and minimize...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the modal view controller

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    self.view.window?.styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask
}
```